# How to get current path when program is loaded dynamically

Tags: java, reflection, jar

I'm not able to give this question an apt title so apology for that.
I am making a modularised application. I load various jar files at runtime and invoke particular method of a particular class (of the jar file) at run time.

The jar file has some supported file. Now my jar file uses another application , lets say `abc` which is located in the same directory where i have kept the jar file. When i run the jar file then

```
new File(".").getAbsolutePath()
```

gives the correct path (this is where `abc` is located) and program runs fine. But when i load this jar file dynamically and invoke method using reflection above code gives the path of the parent program and `abc` is not found at that path.

Now my question is how do i find the path in which my jar file exists when i'm running my jar file's code using reflection.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Put the code where you are  invoking the method through reflection.

Comment: Is your abc within any package?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.class.getResource("StringUtils.class"));
}
```

(Note: `StringUtils` is present on my classpath as a Maven dependency at the time)  This gives me:

```
jar:file:/home/******/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar!/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.class
```

Since the class is in a JAR file, it also gives me the location of the class file within the JAR.